# Reliable cross-platform way of determining hostname from IP address

Tags: networking, ip, remote, dhcp, hostname

Within the DHCP table of a router, clients that have sent their network name are listed with IP and MAC addresses. I need a way to get the host names that clients have sent. The router does not store these entries in it's DNS cache, so using `host` or `nslookup` fails to resolve IP addresses to hostnames.

The router cannot be accessed (via a control interface) or modified in any way, so rectifying this is not an option.

If a client machine is running SMB/Netbios, the machine name name can be discovered, but this will not work for devices such as Ipads, *nix boxes, etc.

Is there a means to achieve what I'm after?

---

Edit:
The solution does not have to be timely, common or standard; hackish ways are welcome. I considered faking a DHCP request for each IP, hoping that the router would reveal information about the already-existing lease, but no cigar; further reading of DHCP ensured..

Answer (score 0):

Stop using DHCP and shift to static IP's instead - that way you can have a hosts table (or internal DNS or whatever), and as the IP addresses of the machines don't change you don't need to worry about dynamic updates.